# How can I get Assets to regenerate S3 thumbnails after cache dir cleared?

Tags: assets, s3

Kicking the tires on the awesome Assets 2.02

When your system/expressionengine/cache directory is cleared, the thumbnails aren't regenerated for files that reside on S3 buckets.

The action calls the method `view_thumbnail()` which returns a broken image. It appears that when the thumbnail is not found, the script tries to resize a file that doesn't exist from `system/expressionengine/cache/assets/s3_sources` (this is where a thumbnail is created when the image is first uploaded).

The thumbnails are regenerated for normal filesystem images, so this is S3 specific.

Please supply a code patch if possible or a fix in the new version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has been fixed in Assets 2.0.3.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. It's not a showstopper so I'll wait for the new release - still just playing. To add, the first time an S3 source is associated, the thumbnails do get generated, so it's just the re-generation that is the problem.

Comment: Right. We just forgot to consider that the cache/assets/s3_sources/ folder might get deleted :)

Comment: Actually the most exciting possibility about Assets 2 is it opens up EE to non-persistent setups (elastic scaling, etc). Busy playing with Heroku at the moment - EE2 and Heroku were a very unlikely combo until now.

Comment: It is true that S3 is only the tip of the iceberg ;)